# How to detect $GOHOSTOS and $GOHOSTARCH at runtime?

Tags: go

How do I detect the value of $GOHOSTOS and $GOHOSTARCH at runtime on any system a go binary is running? Please note that I want to detect these values even if there is no go compiler installation on a host.

Comment: os.Getenv("GOHOSTOS") ?

Comment: Does GOHOSTOS env variable exist, if there is not go compiler installation?

Comment: `runtime.GOOS` and `runtime.GOARCH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version, you can't.

Long version, you can create a build script that embeds the info in your code, for example:

- main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

var (
    hostOS   string
    hostArch string
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("runtime values:", runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
    fmt.Println("build time values:", hostOS, hostArch)
}
```

- build.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# replace main. with whatever package you're using
go build -ldflags "-X main.hostOS=$(go env GOHOSTOS) -X main.hostArch=$(go env GOHOSTARCH)" $*
```

- output:

```
$ env GOARCH=386 ./build.sh
$ ./tmp
runtime values: linux 386
build time values: linux amd64
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

`$GOHOSTOS` and `$GOHOSTARCH` ( serve default values for `GOOS` and `GOARCH` respectively) are used while building of go programs and do not influence the execution of the run-time system.

`GOOS` and `GOARCH` are recorded at compile time and made available by constants `runtime.GOOS` and `runtime.GOARCH`. 
You may want to check these constants.

Comment: where can I find this info? I just deduced the behavior (on my own), and found this lovely answer, but would like to find the reference.